# The meaning of "act in capacity"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> *As a society, we need young people to follow good role models, and so celebrities need to understand that accepting money from advertising means that they are **acting in this capacity**.*

What does the phrase " acting in this capacity" mean?

As far as I know, in this context, "act" means perform/do sth.

The Collins dictionary explains the meaning of "capacity" as: If you do something in a particular capacity, you do it as part of a particular job or duty, or because you are representing a particular organization or person.

The meaning of the whole phrase stills remains vague to me though

Comment: Please state where you found the sentence, give a link or give more context.

Comment: Google leads to [here](https://rhinospike.com/audio_requests/maiphuonghaha/54439/) by "maiphuonghaha"  (Mai Phương) from Vietnam, not a native speaker. Voting to close.

Comment: Just because the author is not a native speaker, does not mean that the expression "to act in the capacity of" does not exist in English. Celebrities are not only actors, so "act" can be the synonym of "function, operate, behave" etc., whereas "in the capacity of" simply means "as".

Comment: The Mai Phuong girl copied that essay from a book about essay writing by Pauline Cullen (The key to IELTS writing task 2)

Comment: Then edit your question to add context before and after that sentence and state where you found it.

Comment: The previous sentence refers to role models, so it appears to mean that, by accepting payment for appearing in advertising, celebrities are acting as (in the capacity of) role models.

Comment: @KateBunting: It's not even "the **previous** sentence"! That vital-but-missing text actually occurs at the beginning of the sentence containing the words OP doesn't understand. I've edited to show the full source sentence, but now I look at it, the question seems utterly trivial for ELU.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes I just realized that my bad. I had no idea why I didn't see that part earlier. I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are "acting in a given capacity" you are performing the function defined by the capacity, the "capacity" being a previously defined position in a society or organisation.

For example if the mayor of a town has resigned and there has not yet been an election for a new one another councillor might perform the duties of the mayor for a while without actually having the title. In that case the councillor would be "acting in the capacity of mayor".

The problem with the sentence as it stands is that the "capacity" is not very well defined. It is possible that a previous sentence has defined it well or that the writer is referring to advertising or to role models as suggested by Kate Bunting.